# Identifying Needed Link Libraries

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm using C++ under Visual Studio 2010 (VS2010). I've pulled in a third-party library provided as headers and libs. The first call I added into this library produced a ton of unresolved symbol link errors. The problem is that there are a *lot* of .lib files in this library. I need to somehow identify the ones I need. I have already added the library *directory* to the VS2010 linker options. Now I just need to identify the individual libraries I need.

Best possible solution: After the link attempt, VS2010 would scan the library directory for the unresolved symbols and would tell me what .lib files contain them.

Barring this, I'd like to solicit ideas from the community on the most efficient way to solve this problem.

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 3):

The documentation is supposed to tell you.  If you don't have any then leave it up to the linker to sort it out.  Add *all* the .libs as Additional Dependencies.

Then take a lazy Friday to sort out which ones you really need with the /VERBOSE linker option, it shows you which .lib is actually getting used in the trace to the Output window.  Project + Properties, Linker, Command line to add the option.